# JQuery BUBBLE CHART- need to display bubbles with different colors

Tags: jquery, bubble-chart

Recently am working with bubble chart usring highchart in jquery. I want to give different cololors to my bubbles. my problem is when is supply color along the data as

```
var data = {[x:30,y:40,r:50,'rgba(0.5,0.6,0.5,0.5)'],
        [x:70,y:80,r:90,'rgba(0.8,0.9,0.5,0.5)']}
```

am getting the bubbles with different colors but with the same radius. I tried setting the colors using the

```
 fillColor: {radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                    stops: [[0, 'rgba(255,50,255,0.5)'],[1, 'rgba(0,25,255,0.5)']]}
```

in the HighCharts.Chart section aslo. But am not able to get bubbles with different colors..

Could anyone help me on this...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data = [{x:30,y:40,z:50,color:'rgba(255,50,255,0.5)'},
        {x:70,y:80,z:90,color:'rgba(0,25,255,0.5)'}];
```

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/7V3uA/